# How to get next index value in my numbers list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume I have a list like;

```
final numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
final generateNumbers = List.generate(numbers.length,
  (i) => numbers.sublist(0, i + 1)).expand((i) => i);
print(generateNumbers);
```

this is my output: 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Now assume I print index 5, that index value is 3 and aim remove all index contains 3.

now need to know next index value after three, I mean that index value is 1.

what's a good way to do this with dart ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get next index value in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779513/how-to-get-next-index-value-in-list)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779513/how-to-get-next-index-value-in-list#comment121552402_68779513

Comment: The value after the first occurrence of any number will always be 1.  As asked before, what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. I think you want to remove all occurrences of a specific number from the generateNumbers list. In that case just use:

```
generateNumbers.removeWhere((element) => element == 1);
```